# Slice of Pi wiring

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiring

I'm trying to wire a Ciseco Slice of Pi.

I need to break out the 3v3, 5v and GND solder pads as I need several of each. There's no track between the pad and the holes I want to use. I could wire them together but then I wouldn't be able to use a header. Is there a header that is connected up internally so I only have to wire the 5v pad to the first pad and then all the header carries 5v?

I've attached a picture if it helps[image: slice of pi with needed connections]

I'm new to this so sorry if this doesn't make sense! Please contact me if you need more information.

Thanks Very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solder a normal header into the board, then run a wire along the header pins on the solder side to connect them together.  I've never seen a header with pins connected together - you always have to make such connections on the PC board.

Comment: Thanks for that! When you say run a wire along the pins on the solder side would you do that with a single piece of wire with the insulation stripped off?

Comment: Yes - just use a bit of bare wire, and solder it to each pin.